# Getting a link from its anchor with Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a list of urls with all the same anchor "view page" among other kind of urls, like this :

```
<a href="url1" target="_blank">view page</a>

<a href="url2" target="_blank">view page</a>
```

Is there a way to extract all the urls with this particular anchor text ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find links with text *view page*, you can use `find_all('a', text='view page')` and then loop through the result set and extract the url from it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<a href="url1" target="_blank">view page</a>
<a href="url2" target="_blank">view page</a>
<a href="url2" target="_blank"></a>""", "html.parser")

[a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', text='view page')]
# [u'url1', u'url2']
```